# JMeter "Validate The Script" - what should I see in the "results tree"?

Tags: jmeter

Following the JMeter step-by-step documentation https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

It says;

[image: image showing section 26.5 of the step by step tutorial called Validate the script]

- What should I see in the "view results tree"?
- How do I know if things are okay or not?
- What does it mean if nothing shows in the results tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Validate` is a feature which appeared in [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30), it basically runs your Test Plan with 1 user in 1 iteration with no pauses if there are Timers in your test plan.

1. In [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you should see all executed requests including request and response details.
2. If request is successful (by default JMeter treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful) - it will be "green", otherwise it will appear as red.
3. If there is nothing in View Results Tree it means either that no requests were executed or you put it into wrong place, View Results Tree listener obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) so it should be at the same level as your [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) (or higher)

   [image]